# Order for pick list in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a quaestion. In configuration of Jenkins I have
[image]

When I switch places, for example I set "SERVICES" in the first position and "G" in the second position and save this configuration, I have the correct order when I run it. But all it takes is for someone to run this pipeline and after re-entering the pipeline I have the old configuration where "G" is in the first position. I also changed everything on branches.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The parameter configuration is defined inside the pipeline -> therefore when you run the pipeline it overrides the configuration. If you want to change the order then change it in the piepline code.